# $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{\{Y\in B\}}|X]=Q(X,B)$ where $Q(x,B):=\sum\limits_{y\in B}\mathbb{P}(Y=y\mid X=x)$?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $X:\Omega\to S_1$ and $Y:\Omega\to S_2$ be two discrete random variables with $P(X=x)>0\;\forall x\in S_1$ and $P(Y=y)>0\;\forall y\in S_2$. I would like to compute the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{\{Y\in B\}}\mid X]$ and in particular show that  $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{\{Y\in B\}}\mid X]=Q(X,B)$ where $Q(x,B):=\sum\limits_{y\in B}\mathbb{P}(Y=y\mid X=x)$. By the average property of conditional expectation I have to show that $$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{\{Y\in B\}}(X)h(X)]=\mathbb{E}[Q(X,B)h(X)]$$ for every $h$ bounded and $\sigma(X)$-measurable. But I have some troubles in expressing $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{\{Y\in B\}}(X)h(X)]$. I think $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{\{Y\in B\}}(X)h(X)]=\int\mathbb{1}_{y\in B}(x)h(x)d\mu_{X,Y}(x,y)$ but then I am not sure what the joint law $\mu_{X,Y}$ actually is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h$ be bounded and measurable. Then

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[1_{\{Y\in B\}}h(X)]
&=\mathbb E\left[\sum_{x\in S_1}1_{\{Y\in B\}}h(x)1_{\{X=x\}}\right]\\
&=\sum_{x\in S_1}h(x)\mathbb E[1_{\{Y\in B,X=x\}}]\\
&=\sum_{x\in S_1}h(x)\mathbb P(Y\in B,X=x)\\
&=\sum_{x\in S_1}h(x)\mathbb P(X=x)\mathbb P(Y\in B\mid X=x)\\
&=\sum_{x\in S_1}h(x)\mathbb P(X=x)Q(x,B)\\
&=\mathbb E[Q(X,B)h(X)]
\end{align*}
$$

PS : no need that $Y$ be discrete.